Minitest mock not handling named parameters
I have a line of code:
@coverage_class.where(original_id: coverage.id, waiting_for_doc_requests: false)
and my unit test is doing the following expect:
mock = Minitest::Mock.new
mock.expect(:where, :results, [{ original_id: :id, waiting_for_doc_requests: false }])

and when running the unit test I get the following error:
Minitest::UnexpectedError: ArgumentError: mocked method :where expects 1 arguments, got []
The parameter array is not accepting the hash as an argument.  All my other calls that do not use named parameters work fine.
Surely this can't be a limitation from Minitest?  Named parameters in Ruby are pretty common nowadays.
Any help would be appreciated!

The method signature for expect is:
def expect name, retval, args = [], **kwargs, &blk

Docs and Source Code.
Right now you are passing what should be keyword arguments as a positional argument of { original_id: :id, waiting_for_doc_requests: false }.
So you can just change your expectation to
mock.expect(:where, :results, original_id: :id, waiting_for_doc_requests: false)


It should be noted that this behavior changed with the separation of keyword arguments in Ruby 3.0. I don't understand though why nobody thought to document how **kwargs is used by the method.

@max I actually tested it in 2.6 and it worked just fine but I agree the docs vaguely mention kwargs are accepted but does not provide an actual example. The change implementing kwargs was added in 5.16.0

Yeah, passing keywords args a hash should work in Ruby 2.6. My point was that there is a lot of now outdated info where they pass kwargs as a hash.
